# If I use kinect2, what should I do? What do I need to install?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Kinect2 , But I don't know what I should to install. So anyone has Tutorials? If have, can you provide the Internet addresses,Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222079/if-i-use-kinect2,-what-should-i-do?-what-do-i-need-to-install-?/) by [MrBin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25270/mrbin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well take a look [here](http://www.ros.org/news/2014/09/microsoft-kinect-v2-driver-released.html) it links you to the information about the kinect2 and ros.
You cannot use plan libfreenect or openni.
But there is a libreenect2 for the kinect2 as described in the above post.
That could be found here: https://github.com/wiedemeyer/libfreenect2

---

Originally posted by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) with karma: 56 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrBin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25270/mrbin/) on 2015-12-08**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) on 2015-12-08**:
If this answers solved your question, you can accept it.